# XPages "filter by category name" for View Panel Controll random error

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

I got a very strange problem with View Panel Controll in IBM XPages.
When I try to make a single category with the option "filter by category name" I got randomly a wrong result back, what means, I got all document back instead of the single category. The key parameter is **not** calculated, so that this is excluded as the reason for my problem.

When I create a simple expample db to see if this is a general bug in XPages, I can't reproduce it. It seems, that it only happens when a lot more stuff is going on in the XPage. And it also depends on the server performance. Maybe a lifecycle problem?

When I do the same with the View Panel property "Filter by column value" I got no problems.
But I can't use it because its a lot slower and it removes the categories after the keycolumn from the view.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

[UPDATE]
In the View Panel is nothing calculated, every property is a fixed String. The singelkey is just like "123456" nothing more. So this can't be the problem. The problem only happens when i add for example 1000 fields with complex formulars to the XPages. But as i sayed the problem is only randomly and i alway use the same values for the properties. It must be a timing thing.

[UPDATE2]
When the `<xp:viewPanel>` it the only element on my XPage everything works fine, when i add a `<xp:inputText value="COMPLEX SSJS OR JAVA METHOD">` a 1000 times to the XPages as well, it don't work anymore. When i set my key parmeter to the property "filter by column value" with a flat view it always works. But this solution did not work for me (the statement why is above)

Comment: I have noticed something like this.  When you calc the key and/or category, if the result is null then all documents are returned.  I had a workaround, let me think about how I did it since it has been a while.

Comment: Please have a look to my Update

Answer (score 1):

Pixel,

I think this is as simple as having an else that returns something that will never occur.  If the category returns a null for any reason, it will return all documents.  Having the else that returns something that will never happen should fix your problem.

```
<xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(category == "FilteredCategory"){
    return "your category"
} else {
    return "never-a-category";
}}]]></xp:this.categoryFilter>
```

If this isn't the answer, then please post your code in your question.

Comment: Can you verify that the first column of the view is sorted?

Comment: It is sorted and categorised. When i open the page the first time it works perfect, but when i try it another time, probably not

Comment: Is there a way you can rephrase "The problem only happens when i add for example 1000 fields with complex formulars to the XPages."  I am not understanding what you mean in this sentence.  Please edit your question instead of replying to your comment.

Comment: If you are using "keys" instead of a category filter, then try making your view flat.  A flat view has no categories.  Make the key column the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the question update.  Tough one.  Is the view panel in the same container as all these input fields?  I haven't ever experienced the upper limits of controls on a single page. You might want to consider a different design strategy.  Maybe put the viewPanel in its own custom control and see if that helps.

Comment: It is already in his own controll...The funny thing is..when i set the pager from the header to the footer in the viewPanel, it cause rarely.

Comment: Could be a bug.  Are you using the pager save state control?  If not, then try it, if so then remove it and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Sorry Pixel, I am out of suggestions. Hope you are able to figure it out.