# View Column Header cannot sort column when use Filter by category name?

Tags: xpages

I have a view in the xpage. The view will display relevant information depends on user login. In my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160841/xpages-refresh-the-view-when-different-user-login), thanks for the useful answer and comments, I was able to do the part.

However, I notice that the view cannot sort when click the column header. In Properties, I go to View Column Header, I see the Sort column has a tick in the check box.

I am not sure why the view column header cannot sort, I guess the Filter by category name effect the sort function. It is because when I remove the code in Filter by category name, I can click the column header to sort. But when I add the add code in Filter by category name, I click the column header, it cannot sort.

So my question is why the view column header cannot sort column when use filter by category name? Is there any method that I can make view column header able to sort when clicked?

I would like to post my code below because I don't know which part I did wrong.

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel3"
                    pageName="/BookVenue.xsp" iewStyle="width:700.0px">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
                            layout="Previous Group Next"    xp:key="footerPager" id="pager1">
                        </xp:pager>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView var="view1"
                            viewName="UserBookedVenueInfo">
                            <xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#  {javascript:var uName:NotesName =   session.createName(session.getEffectiveUserName());
 return uName.getCommon();

}]]></xp:this.categoryFilter>
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Venue"
                        id="viewColumn7" displayAs="link">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Course Name"
                            id="viewColumnHeader7" sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ReturnDate"
                        id="viewColumn8" displayAs="link">
                        <xp:this.converter>
                            <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
                                dateStyle="long">
                            </xp:convertDateTime>
                        </xp:this.converter>
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Remarks"
                            id="viewColumnHeader8" sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Remark"
                        id="viewColumn9" displayAs="link">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Remark"
                            id="viewColumnHeader9" sortable="true">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                </xp:viewPanel>
```

Would someone let me know my mistakes please. Thanks a lot.

I have read the following posts and I try to use the solution in the view but it still cannot sort.

[XPages "filter by category name" for View Panel Controll random error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204214/xpages-filter-by-category-name-for-view-panel-controll-random-error)

[xpages : Filtering a View Data Source using the keys parameter(filter by category name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631364/xpages-filtering-a-view-data-source-using-the-keys-parameterfilter-by-categor)

Comment: Works as designed. When you filter a categorised view there is no sorting. You would use client side code to sort

Comment: @stwissel, thanks for your comment. I think I have to use client side code to make the view column hader able to sort when clicked.

Comment: Sorry may I a question about the client side code please? In the designer, I click the view column header, in properties tab, I see there is a diamond symbol near the sort column. I click the diamond symbol and choose compute value. Then a script editor comes up, I realise the language is JavaScript(Server Side), I click the combo box and  I only find JavaScript(Server Side), Expression Language (EL) and Custom for selection.

Comment: Maybe I should select Custom and try to write some client side code in there.

Comment: May be switch to jQuery data tables and feed it via an Java Bean, http://www.slideshare.net/MichaelSmith200/mwlug-2016-ad117-xpages-jquery-datatables

Answer (score 1):

You may want to just ditch the View Control and use a repeat and store the data in a Java object. Then you can sort for any of the columns. I covered this in a webinar I did, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln-meA0WXaw&feature=youtu.be

The sample database is at http://www.tlcc.com/mwlug

Howard

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask a question please. So do you mean I should put java code in the view in order to make the column headers sort-able? If so, where can I write the java code?

Comment: In Designer, I click Window, I select Open Perspective, and then I choose Java. At this moment, I notice the interface of the Designer has a little bit difference. I can see Package Explorer and Hierachy. In Package Explorer, there are various folders with meaningful name, e.g. Local, AppProperties, Code, etc. I notice there is a folder name called Xpages. I click it and it seems shows all xsp files that I have in the application. I open the xsp file that the view located there. I do not see any place that I can write java code. Do I missed which place to write java code?

Comment: Probably best if you watch my webinar and look at the sample database. By Java, I mean a Java code element configured as a managed bean. The repeat control is bound to a method on that bean. The search/sort criteria on that XPage is also bound to the bean so when the repeat is rendered the method returns the set of data that is sorted per the user specs.